# how to prevent normal-user from opening port

Tags: linux, port

In linux,since normal-user can open ports above 1024- does any one know how to prevent normal-user from opening any port on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can disallow users to bind to a port, but you can firewall them. Iptables has "owner" support, that might give you the options you need.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - I'll check iptables. But I also need to know how to prevent user from starting a port. on my system has plenty of normal user can login into it. He can write a simple C program or python to open a new port.  how to avoid that?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/185287/how-to-prevent-normal-user-from-opening-port/185289#185289

Comment: :) :) Are you sure ,is that correct url ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: I assume "bind" is different from "opening" a port. In programming terms, client can "bind" to server which is listening for client connection. What you have suggested is how to prevent client from connecting to server- that's different from my requirement which is " how to prevent user from opening a port".If i'm wrong let me know.

Comment: I think your requirements are a bit blurry.. "Opening a port" can mean connecting to a remote server port or opening a local port and listen. The security extensions aside, you can block users making outgoing connections by firewalling them and you can block incoming connections by firewalling them..

Comment: oh..i never knew "opening port" refers to "connecting to remote port" .I'll look into firewall and iptables.thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

All the common security extensions for Linux like SELinux, grsecurity, AppArmor or Tomoyo enable you to forbid normal users to bind to any UDP or TCP socket or to specify which sockets they can bind to.